# Prevent top left hotspot corner in fedora 15

Tags: fedora

How can I prevent top left hotcorner in fedora 15? Sometimes my mouse accidently moves to the top left corner while I'm working.

Comment: for those of us who don't use Fedora, perhaps explain in a sentence or two what the "left hotspot" corner does?

Comment: By left corner hotspot, I mean, when I hover the top left corner of the screen, then my windows are shown as thumbnails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this guide](http://z4ziggy.wordpress.com/2011/05/04/disable-gnome-shell-hotspot/) for instructions. There's no preferences settings, so you'll have to patch a file.

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to put a click on Fedora 15 hotcorner which was really annoying, check this entry http://ask.fedoraproject.org/question/730/how-to-force-a-click-on-hotcorner-on-fedora-15